# Clean 21.04 and Wayland not working properly with screen sharing

Tags: remote-desktop, wayland, 21.04

I have a clean install of 21.04 minimal using Wayland, and I installed `gnome-remote-desktop` and enabled screen sharing.  From my upgraded 21.04 machine I VNC into the clean install machine, but functionality is very limited.

- Application windows cannot be moved or resized - I can "select" windows to grab focus, though.
- Windows (including their menus) are non-reactive to my mouse clicks (left- and right-clicks).
- "Show Application" works, and I can launch apps.  Mouse clicks on the favorites work.
- In Terminal, I can type and run commands, but I can't open new tabs.
- I can access the Activity menu, and launch Settings, but I can't select any of the menu items.  I can "tab" through fields on the Settings windows, but it skips over the menu items, so they are not selectable.

Basically, remote desktop sharing is useless.  It's almost as if it's read only, except I can do thing that shouldn't be possible in read-only.

I need full functionality and control.  Am I missing a package and/or configuration?

Comment: Same problem if you select "Ubuntu on Xorg" at login time?

Comment: yes, it works when using xorg.

Comment: May be a Wayland or sharing app problem. Maybe a video driver problem. When you installed "21.04 minimal using Wayland", maybe that didn't install all required software. You might try doing a full install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed because of Wayland, not supporting (yet?) everything that Xorg supports. Applications need to be updated to play well with Wayland (while, arguably, it should the the other way round). Eventually, VNC will be updated to play with Wayland, but in the mean time, you may prefer to switch back to Xorg.

Comment: yeah, that's my only options right now.